# TRichMemo - LoadRichText not working

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to save the contents of a TRichMemo to TMemoryStream, and then be able to load the formatted data back from the stream into the rich memo.

The problem is `LoadRichText` is failing for some reason. I know the data is been saved to my stream because I can actually save it fo file as rtf and view it externally.

This is basically what I have:

```
var
  FMyStream: TMemoryStream;
```

To save:

```
RichMemo1.SaveRichText(FMyStream);
```

To load:

```
FMyStream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
if not RichMemo1.LoadRichText(FMyStream) then
  raise Exception.Create('Failed to load data from stream.');
```

As I said the data is saved to stream correctly, but trying to load into the rich memo is hitting my exception everytime.

What could be the problem?

The code for the `LoadRichText` function is:

```
function TCustomRichMemo.LoadRichText(Source: TStream): Boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(Source) and HandleAllocated then begin
    Result := TWSCustomRichMemoClass(WidgetSetClass).LoadRichText(Self, Source);
    if not Result and Assigned(RTFLoadStream) then begin
      Self.Lines.BeginUpdate;
      Self.Lines.Clear;
      Result:=RTFLoadStream(Self, Source);
      Self.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end else
    Result := false;
end;
```

and `SaveRichText` code:

```
function TCustomRichMemo.SaveRichText(Dest: TStream): Boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(Dest) and HandleAllocated then begin
    Result := TWSCustomRichMemoClass(WidgetSetClass).SaveRichText(Self, Dest);
    if not Result and Assigned(RTFSaveStream) then
      Result:=RTFSaveStream(Self, Dest);
  end else
    Result := false;
end;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to my problem.

At first I created a simple test project and `LoadRichText` and `SaveRichText` worked, which meant the problem was within my code somewhere...

My stream is declared in a class in a separate unit. In another form I have my rich memo control, when the form is closed the data is saved to the stream, that part I knew worked because I could save it to file and view it externally.

The problem was when I was creating the form that contains my rich memo, I was calling `LoadRichText` from the `FormCreate` event. So I moved it into `FormActivate` and now it works without error.

Comment: `HandleAllocated` was the failing test then.. It would be nice if the code would raise an exception on fail, instead of returning a boolean.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes an exception would be better than a boolean, this one of those errors you just sometimes get lucky at finding.